# How do I configure GIT on Ubuntu (permissions) so multiple users can read/write and push/pull files for Apache2

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I would like to set up GIT & Apache2 on Ubuntu so that multiple Ubuntu/GIT users can push/pull files read by Apache2.

I can set up a user on Ubuntu that has their own GIT repository where they can push/pull from within their own /home/user/ folder using an SSH private key from within /home/user/.ssh/ with the public key on the GIT server (e.g. bitbucket).

However, if that user is given sudo privileges and goes into the Apache2 /var/www/html/ web root directory, they no longer have permission to push to git over ssh (as git is looking for the id_rsa of the root user).  One work around is to set up an .ssh keypair for the root user to access GIT, but then GIT commits are not separated by user (defeating one of the main purposes of version control).

Comment: The most straightforward is probably to make the files group-writeable and add the users to that group.

Comment: I'm wondering what you mean with "...but then GIT commits are not separated by user". The users that will be saved on the revisions are the ones who "commit" (or author) code, not the person "pushing" and that does not depend on transport.

Comment: @Adrian, thank you.  I added user to www-data group then chmod -R g+rwx <repo-name>.  The user is on the repo and their public ssh key is on their profile, yet git push -u origin master from their user (not sudo) returns with repository access denied. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.  If they sudo in, it works.  Is that the best practice, or can the user do it all from within their user (without sudo)?

Comment: @Edmundo, so is it typical for collaborating programmers to do all the commits from within their user (without sudo privileges), and then have an admin push from within root, or is it better to give each programmer root access?

Comment: Though I don't have any experience using with through https, I'm sure it can be set up to authenticate users without having to provide root access on the server. https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Answer (score 1):

Add the user to the www-data group of Apache2

Comment: But web files I write as user:www-data still cannot be read by Apache2, unless I sudo in and write them as www-data:www-data - then they cannot be pushed by GIT over ssh using my key files.